# Jump to item - not to chapter with "\nameref"

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, nameref

I use a "description" environment and want to refer to certain items by name (which works fine). But I also want, that when a reader clicks on the resulting hyperlink that one jumps directly to the item then, not to the chapter, in which the description appears.
Is this somehow possible?

Here is a MWE, which shows the problem - when clicking on the nameref, the PDF reader jumps to the beginning of the chapter:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First sec}

\lipsum
\begin{description}
    \item [My first item\label{it:one}]
    This is my first item
\end{description}
\lipsum

Here I want to refer to my \nameref{it:one} and jump to it, when I click on it.

\end{document}
```

Can anybody assist me here?

Thanks

matse

Comment: Discription items does not have anchors that hyperref can grab on to try using `\phantomsection\label(it:one}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Description items (like `itemize` items) does not produce an anchor that `hyperref` can grab and point towards. Thus `\label` will use the nearest anchor, which is this case is from the `\chapter` command.

Solution: add `\phantomsection` before `\label`, this creates an anonymous anchor for `hyperref` to grab and point towards.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!